# What's an efficient way to skip 0 coefficients when evaluating a polynomial?

Tags: c++, performance, polynomials

I'm working on a microchip with a single core (the stm32f103c8t6) and I want to evaluate some polynomial up to a predetermined exponent, so `f(x) = a0 + a1*x +a2*x^2 +...+an*x^n` where **n** is known at compile time.

The coefficients **a0...an** will change during runtime and a few of them are very likely to become zero and I want to find a way to skip those when evaluating **f(x)**. Note, most will be non-zero. Ideally I would want to rewrite **f(x)** during runtime so the coefficients which are zero are no longer in the function, but I don't want to go into self modifying code territory (unless there's some easy way to do it in C++). The microchip is capable of single instruction multiplication, so any solution equivalent to having if statements to check if the coefficient is zero would be the same or slower than just evaluating the expression as a whole.

The evaluations will happen many times so even saving a single cycle on evaluating the function is helpful. Currently I don't have a viable solution for this and I'm simply evaluating the polynomial as a whole.

I'm writing in C++ for the microchip, though I'm currently working on the algorithms in python since it's easier to plot results and such so I don't have any code for the problem.

Comment: Think about the algorithm you would use for this.  You would calculate (say) x^3 from x^2 * x, and so on, so worrying about zero coefficients is pointless.

Comment: Are you worried about the performance of `a * x ^ n` if `a` is 0? If you end up writing code in c++, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Doing this on a microchip where every cycle counts, so I don't want to waste cycles. I'm going to evaluate this many times so even saving a single cycle each iteration quickly adds up, that's why I don't want to waste cycles calculating 0*x^n. Doesn't matter if I evaluate the whole polynomial "sequentially", I'll still have to waste a cycle for every coefficient that's 0.

Comment: May you please provide your actual technical implementation (your source code of your calculation and source code of using those calculation)? So we may give you an adequate answer? PS I'm thinking a finite state machine would answer your problem, but I'm not 100% sure, because I can't overlook your entire technical problem.

Comment: @BeaconofWierd `a microchip where every cycle counts` How about bytes, then? Clever tricks that save cycles have a tendency to require more code and/or memory. You should provide some context, as well as the baseline implementation that you hope to improve upon.

Answer (score 3):

As an initial step, recall that it is usually better to compute polynomials in some other way than the usual presentation:

```
polynomial = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4 + a5*x^5 + ...
           = a0 + x*(a1 + x*(a2 + x*(a3 + x*(a4 + x*(a5 + ... )...)
           = (a0 + x*a1) + x^2*(a2 + x*a3) + x^4*((a4 + x*a5) + x^2*(a6 + x*a7)) + ...
```

The first line is the conventional presentation, and has the problem that you can end up abusing your dynamic range.

The second line tends to avoid the numerical problems with computing successive powers of x, and is a fairly conventional way to actually compute polynomials.  Unfortunately, it still has a long chain of dependencies, which limits the instruction-level parallellism you can get from it.

The third line avoids the long chain of dependencies, and is also ideally suited for exploiting a vector unit if you have one.

---

From your comment discussion, it sounds like you're working with a low-powered embedded processor.  So, let's assume no vector processor and not much in the way of ILP available anyway, and adapt the second line.  (I will write this in terms of floating point, but it should be readily adaptable to fixed-point).

First, the straightforward method, without trying to skip zero-coefficients:

```
int max_idx = a.size() - 1;
float result = a[max_idx];
int i = max_idx;
while (i > 0) {
  -- i;
  result = a[i] + x * result;
}
return result;
```

Now, the clever method:  assuming your coefficients are fixed, you can preprocess them to determine what powers of `x` you can skip, and therefore which incremental powers you will need to compute (once, ahead of time):

```
// compute powers between nonzero coefficients
int max_idx = a.size() - 1;
assert(a[max_idx] != 0); // you should not have leading zeroes in the first place

std::vector<int> inc_powers;
std::vector<int> inc_indices;
int inc_pow = 0;
int i = max_idx;
while (i > 0) {
  -- i;
  ++ inc_pow;
  if (a[i] != 0 || i == 0) {
    inc_powers.push_back(inc_pow);
    inc_indices.push_back(i);
    inc_pow = 0;
  }
}
```

To evaluate the polynomial:

```
int i = a.size() - 1;
float result = a[i];
for (int i = 0; i < inc_powers.size(); ++i) {
  result = a[inc_indices[i]] + x_powers[inc_powers[i]] * result;
}
return result;
```

You will need to compute `x_powers` -- an array of powers of x used in the above polynomial computation.  There is probably some clever way to compute and specify a minimum computation to generate exactly the powers of x you will need, but it will probably be about as fast (for small polynomials on a slow processor without ILP) to generate them incrementally.  You will need to determine (once, ahead of time) how many powers you need:

```
int max_powers = 0;
for (power: inc_powers) {
  if (power > max_powers) { max_powers = power; }
}
std::vector<float> x_powers(max_powers + 1);
```

Then, for each evaluation, compute them successively as prep for computing the polynomial value:

```
float value = x;
for (int i = 1; i < max_powers; ++i) {
  x_powers[i] = value;
  value *= x;
}
x_powers[max_powers] = value;
```

(I have set things up so that `x_powers[i] == x^i` and `x_powers[0]` is unused.  Hopefully that will make things easier to follow; of course in practice you don't have to do it that way...)

(In a similar spirit, note that you can just copy the nonzero coefficients instead of using an index -- but it might be more instructive as is, so I'll leave it that way)

---

Finally, since you are concerned about performance, you need to actually benchmark both the straightforward and the clever version to make sure your "improvement" is actually an improvement.

Comment: Won't the for loop add an if statement before each iteration in the loop during evaluation? Or will the compiler change this to sequence of "fixed" instructions if I tell the compiler to optimize for speed? :)

Comment: Thinking about this solution some more, the compiler can't convert this to a fixed set of instructions, can it? Since `max_powers` isn't known at compile time? Then this solution would be exactly the same as simply checking `if (coeff != 0)` before evaluating every term?

Comment: There will be one test per *nonzero* coefficient in the polynomial evaluation.  If (as seems likely for the question's use case) there are multiple evaluations with the same set of coefficients, you have the potential to save some time.

Comment: I don't mean during the calculation of `inc_powers` and `inc_indices`, I mean during the actual evaluation of the polynomial itself. Inside the loop `for (int i = 0; i < inc_powers.size(); ++i)` which evaluates the polynomial, since `inc_powers.size()` can't be known at compile time the loop has to check the condition every time in the loop, hence adding an "if statement" for each coefficient which is calculated. Since multiplying is the same speed (one cycle) as an if statement, won't this be as fast or slower than the "straight forward" evaluation?

Comment: The whole point of the preprocessing step is to skip 0-coefficients (as requested in the question).  The size of `inc_powers` and `inc_indices` is the number of *non-zero* coefficients.

Say your polynomial has only odd-powered non-zero coefficients:  then `inc_powers` and `inc_indices` will be roughly half the size of `a`, and your "clever" evaluation will have roughly half the number of tests.

Comment: Sure, but I will probably only have 1 or 2 out of say 6 coefficients which are 0. So the condition check and  `++i` would be more expensive than simply doing those two 0 multiplications, right? Maybe I should update the question again to specify that only a few coefficients will be zero, sorry about that. I'm starting to feel like I should just try to make sure there's no zero coefficients to begin with rather than finding advanced ways to deal with them :P

Comment: You're right, of course:  if you only expect a small number of 0-coefficients, you won't save time by skipping them.  In fact, if you have a small, fixed total number of coefficients, unrolling the loop is a no-brainer (easy for the compiler to find), and is likely impossible to beat with anything clever.

Comment: Ok, I was only asking because this felt like a "regular" problem which should have an easy solution like using some sort of function pointer or something, but I guess the only way to this "properly" would be to modify the evaluation function on runtime and that's way beyond my skill set, I'm not that good with assembly :(

Comment: If you generated an exponential number of functions, one for each possible pattern of 0-coefficients, you could select a function pointer to one of the `2^n` functions.  That might even be practical for `n==6 -> 2^n==64` if you have the room.  However, I'm not sure that would fly for an embedded processor.

Comment: Hmm, might be an option :) Memory wise I have something like 128 kB, so not a lot but not nothing either. Since I will have a fairly good idea of which terms might be zero I might not need that many functions. The coefficients are for a differential equation so I know for sure which won't be zero, it will only be higher order terms I'm unsure about. Is there really no way to write a function at runtime in C++? :S

Comment: @BeaconofWierd `doing those two 0 multiplications` This makes it sound like the evaluation would follow the `a_k * x^k` pattern, but that's not the case (except maybe in the naive implementation). In the standard Horner method (2nd line in the answer), all coefficients but the last one are *summed* with something, not *multiplied* with anything. In other words, the number of required multiplications does not change if you somehow skip over the zero coefficients, just the number of additions. To optimize beyond that you'd need some trickery about calculating the powers of `x` across "gaps".

Comment: @dxiv The microprocessor I’m working on takes the same amount of time (one cycle) to preform a multiplication as an addition, so saving one addition or multiplication is equivalent.

Comment: @BeaconofWierd In that case it's unlikely you can do any meaningful optimization, short of self-modifying code or 2^N static copies of customized codes. Just reading/using the coefficients in any way gives a lower bound of N cycles. Horner's scheme gives an upper bound of 2N cycles. Between those two bounds, any runtime check and/or branch will likely take at least one additional cycle per step, so the 2N bound will be hard to beat.

Comment: @dxiv You're probably right, though 2^N static copies might actually be worth it since my N won't be that big :) The better route is probably to just make sure I don't include any terms which might become zero, hopefully they won't have much of an impact on the performance of the system... Hopefully :P

Answer (score 0):

Related: [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) and some [Robinson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%27s_joint_consistency_theorem). IIRC your problem is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) or at least [intractable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Intractability), and related to [P versus NP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem). Try using [REDUCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduce_(computer_algebra_system)).

Notice that [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/)  is probably a better place to ask

You could try [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) and [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) techniques

#### You certainly can get a PhD by working on this topic.

Study the source code of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), of [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC) and of the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). Both are doing such [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (with more or less success). Consider also using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/).

> I'm sure this problem already has a solution but I couldn't find it

### As far as I know, your problem has no exact solution

and if you find one, you would get the [Turing award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_Award).

Read J.Pitrat's [*Artificial Beings: the Conscience of a Conscious Machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015) (ISBN 978-1848211018) book. It is giving useful insights on your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Using a finite state machine. You need to write the code for every possible state. But this is probably the fastest possible way to calculate.

This is an example, it uses example math-functions and an example value of iterations. OP has to provide his own math-functions and own value of iteration for each state.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    /* MAX_COEFFICIENTS <-- states == 2^coefficients */
    const int MAX_COEFFICIENTS = 3;
    int coefficientsv[] = {1, 0, 3}; /* {A, B, C} */
    int coefficientsc = sizeof coefficientsv / sizeof coefficientsv[0];
    if(coefficientsc > MAX_COEFFICIENTS) return -1; /* Out of bounds! */
    
    register int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < coefficientsc; i++){
        if(i == 0) A = coefficientsv[i];
        else if(i == 1) B = coefficientsv[i];
        else if(i == 2) C = coefficientsv[i];
    }
    
    register long polycalc = 0; /* or use just int, if int is big enough */
    register int iteration = 1000; /* example value */
    
    /* state truth table    */
    /* A B C                */
    /* 0 0 0 goto STATE_0   */
    /* 1 0 0 goto STATE_A   */
    /* 0 1 0 goto STATE_B   */
    /* 1 1 0 goto STATE_AB  */
    /* 0 0 1 goto STATE_C   */
    /* 1 0 1 goto STATE_AC  */
    /* 0 1 1 goto STATE_BC  */
    /* 1 1 1 goto STATE_ABC */

    STATE_SELECT:
    if(!A && !B && !C) goto STATE_0;
    if( A && !B && !C) goto STATE_A;
    if(!A &&  B && !C) goto STATE_B;
    if( A &&  B && !C) goto STATE_AB;
    if(!A && !B &&  C) goto STATE_C;
    if( A && !B &&  C) goto STATE_AC;
    if(!A &&  B &&  C) goto STATE_BC;
    if( A &&  B &&  C) goto STATE_ABC;
    
    STATE_0:
    while(iteration){
        polycalc = 0;
        iteration--;
    }
    goto END;
    
    STATE_A:
    while(iteration){
        polycalc = A;
        iteration--;
    }
    goto END;
    
    STATE_B:
    while(iteration){
        polycalc = B * B;
        iteration--;
    }
    goto END;
    
    STATE_AB:
    while(iteration){
        polycalc = A + B * B;;
        iteration--;
    }
    goto END;
    
    STATE_C:
    while(iteration){
        polycalc = C * C * C;
        iteration--;
    }
    goto END;
    
    STATE_AC:
    while(iteration){
        polycalc = A + C * C * C;
        iteration--;
    }
    goto END;
    
    STATE_BC:
    while(iteration){
        polycalc = B * B + C * C * C;
        iteration--;
    }
    goto END;
    
    STATE_ABC:
    while(iteration){
        polycalc = A + B * B + C * C * C;
        iteration--;
    }
    /* Example: Pseudo-Code */
    /* Maybe your first calculation has shown that C becomes 0. */
    /* So simply use "goto STATE_AB", maybe set some variables. */
    /* In another example, you only know that some coefficient */
    /* has become 0, but you don't know which one, */
    /* so use "goto STATE_SELECT", maybe set some variables too. */
    goto END;
    
    END:
    std::cout << polycalc << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP wrote "*the polynomial would be evaluated as* `a0+a1x+a2x^2`". Your code appears to be calculating `a0 + a1^2 + a2^3` instead, 1000 times over. How is that even related, let alone "*fastest*"?

Comment: @dxiv Read again what the problem of OP is. The main goal is to eliminate the **"if coefficient == 0 then don't calc"**, which my program clearly does. I'm using example values and example math-functions, which have to be changed by OP.

Comment: 1) The OP looks to optimize evaluation of a polynomial for different values of the variable, which the answer does not even mention. 2) Assuming you fixed that, the approach does not scale, since the number of cases grows exponentially with the degree of the polynomial. 3) Even for a quadratic with only 2^1 + 1 = 3 coefficients the code is suboptimal, there is a needless `for` loop, then 2^3 = 8 `if`s + `goto`s instead of 1 `switch` or a function dispatch. I will un-downvote if you post something  at least on par with default [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: _Now say some of those coefficients are 0 as a result of some updates and/or user input, ideally I would want to remove those terms when evaluating the function so I don't have to calculate x^5 and then just throw it away because the coefficient was 0. ... **I also want to do this as efficiently as possible (without going into the territory of writing self modifying code), so ideally no if statements to check if each coefficient is 0 before evaluating each term or anything like that but maybe a chain of some pointer magic or something?**_ OP uses embedded machine where every CPU cycle counts!

Comment: @dxiv PS _Doing this on a microchip where every cycle counts, so I don't want to waste cycles. **I'm going to evaluate this many times so even saving a single cycle each iteration quickly adds up...**_ There is the iteration, your "needless" `for` loop. Maybe the problem is that OP wasn't very clear in writing his question. PPS What do you think is a switch with 8 cases?

Comment: The needless `for` loop is the one that does `A = coefficientsv[0];` and similar for `B`, `C`. And, for example `switch((A == 0) + ((B == 0) << 1) + ((C == 0) << 2))` with `case 0:` to `case 7:`.

Comment: No, this isn't the "needless" `for`, because you'll always have at least 1 `if` to determine if the value is zero or non zero. As far as I understand, OP reads a polynomial and does multiple operations onto it, he iterates it, that's why I was using states. You really think this switch is faster? It isn't.

Comment: Possibly faster, certainly no worse, and I'll leave it at that since this seems to be going nowhere.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry, but you have no idea how a CPU works. Your switch is doing multiple comparations and mathematical operations and several jumps and even some binary shifts, while I use NOT-AND-junctions followed with a single jump.